# get the top page(masterpage) using javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, master-pages

I'am using a masterpage and inside the is an iframe and inside the iframe i sometimes have another iframe.
So i want to get the masterpage using javascript.

I am using this but for some reason it loops and never stops.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
   var wind = window;
   while(wind.parent!=null)
   {
     wind=wind.parent;
   }
   wind.document.getElementById('consultar processos').style.color = "#D10759";
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) is your friend :)

> Returns a reference to the topmost window in the window hierarchy.
>   Where the window.parent property returns the immediate parent of the
>   current window, window.top returns the topmost window in the hierarchy
>   of window objects.
>
> This property is especially useful when you are dealing with a window
>   that is in a subframe of a parent or parents, and you want to get to
>   the top-level frameset.